# How to "obtain a long list of all processes that are in memory" (Linux)

Tags: linux, cmd

Hey guys im currently studying for an exam and one question that keeps coming up is
(a) Give the Linux shell commands to achieve the following:
"Obtain a long list of all processes that are in memory"

I am confused on the correct answer for this question.

I think it's either `ps aux` or `ps -l`

I've tried googling this for a long time but i cannot find out which way is correct if it even is one of those two ways.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: cmd tag is WINDOWS command shell. Use `tasklist` in windows.

Answer (score 0):

If prompt type

top command : Display and update sorted information about processes.
atop : Advanced System & Process Monitor.
htop : Interactive process viewer.

Ref: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/